# How can I change the background color of a PHP block in eclipse PDT?

Tags: eclipse, themes, aptana, eclipse-pdt

I've seen it done in some of the Aptana themes, but don't know how to do it with eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `Preferences -> General -> Colors and Fonts` and you will see something in there related to the PHP editor.

Comment: it's not there, in fact in my apatana there are no php settings

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this project:

http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/